# File ended while scanning use of \eqref

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to refer to multiple equations with `\eqref` but LaTeX seems unwilling. It always displays

> "File ended while scanning use of \eqref."

and produces corrupt `.aux` files which I remove before running again...

Here a simple version of my code:

```
%minimal working example

\documentclass[a4paper,
11pt,
bibliography=totocnumbered,
listof=numbered,
captions=tableheading,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
1=1 \label{eq:mom}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2=2 \label{eq:m_masse} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
3=3 \label{eq:m_r} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
4=4 \label{eq:m_d}
\end{equation}

Einsetzen von Gleichungen \eqref{eq:m_masse), \eqref{eq:m_r} und 
\eqref{eq:m_d} in die Gleichung \eqref{eq:mom} ergibt:

\end{document}
```

Help would be awesome :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\eqref{eq:m_masse)` is wrong, it should be `\eqref{eq:m_masse}`, i.e. with the curly brace, not the right parenthesis. The error message `File ended while scanning` is very often caused by a missing `}`

Comment: Just a typo change the \eqref{eq:m_masse)` that @ChristianHupfer said first to `\eqref{eq:m_masse}`.... I will vote to close this question. And Welcome to TeX.SE! Bravo for providing a MWE even if you are a new member (many of them doesn't)! Edit: Can not find something about "typo"... Someone else can flag it...

Comment: I must sadly confess it was only a typo. Am very sorry to bother you with such trivialities. And thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo, acknowledged in the comments.

Comment: @koleygr -- the "off-topic" choice is what you want here.  it gives you the option to add a custom reason.  (not ideal, but the closest available.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton.. thanks... I had just found this reason some more times and thought it is a standard reason as the others there and that I could not find at the moment...